# How To Get Product Quantity?

Tags: magento2, registry, get

I have tried using this code, but it doesn't return the product's quantity

```
private $registry;

  public function __construct(
    Template\Context $context,
    Registry $registry,
    array $data = []
  )
  {
      parent::__construct($context, $data);
      $this->registry = $registry;
  }
  
  public function getCurrentStock(){
    $product = $this->getCurrentProduct();
    return $product->getQty();
  }

  public function getCurrentProduct(){
    return $this->registry->registry('product');
  }
```

but if I change

```
return $product->getQty();
```

to

```
return $product->getCreatedAt();
```

it will return the products created_at date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject the StockRegistryInterface interface where you need access:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface
 */
private $stockRegistry;

/**
 * Constructor for DI.
 *
 * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
) {
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
}

/**
 * Get the product stock data and methods.
 *
 * @return \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface
 */
public function getStockRegistry()
{
    return $this->stockRegistry;
}
```

To use it somewhere:

```
/** @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry */
$stockRegistry = [$this|$block]->getStockRegistry();

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
$product = [Grab Product instance however you want. This is up to you.]

// Get stock data for given product.
$productStock = $stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());

// Get quantity of product.
$productQty = $productStock->getQty();
```

Comment: thank you so much. :D